# How to setup a nest.js app that connects to two separate kafka instances?

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs

I have a requirement for a kafka "consumer" app that responds to topics from two separate kafka instances.

[image: kafka nest.js]

I see that nest.js has support to define controllers that are triggered whenever a message is received in a particular topic. This works well with one kafka source, but how do I segregate my "dragon" handlers from my "shark" handlers?

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-microservice-uyq9mz?file=/src/main.ts

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        clientId: 'dragon-service',
        brokers: ['localhost:9093'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'consumer-dragon',
      },
    },
  });

  await app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        clientId: 'shark-service',
        brokers: ['localhost:9094'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'consumer-shark',
      },
    },
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservices();

  Logger.log(` Kafka consumer service is running`);
}

bootstrap();
```

In the above example, the controller is being triggered twice whenever a topic is received from either kafka.

Comment: Why are you running two Kafka clusters on localhost, anyway? Why cant you simply have two topics in one cluster?

Comment: For higher environments I would have two separate existing Kafka clusters. For my local env, I'm using localhost to represent both the "shark" cluster and the "dragon" cluster. (with different topics like you said)

Comment: Could you not use a tool like MirrorMaker to replicate data from one cluster into another? Then your client only needs to connect to one cluster? More specifically, I don't think this is a supported pattern by NestJS, although, you may be able to use kafkajs directly to do this